# H2 issues : request works in H2 console, not in jUnit test

Tags: java, h2

I encounter a problem with **H2 Database**, I can't figure out what this problem is.

I'm working on a 3 alphanums code generator that should behave by incrementing by one the highest existing code (this is a SQL function that will be stored on the DB server).

The following code works perfectly in **H2 console** :

```
SELECT TOP 1 concat(a.Chr, b.Chr, c.Chr) AS REF
FROM 
(VALUES('0'),('1'),('2'),('3'),('4'),('5'),('6'),('7'),('8'),('9'),('A'),('B'),('C'),('D'),('E'),('F'),('G'),('H'),('I'),('J'),('K'),('L'),('M'),('N'),('O'),('P'),('Q'),('R'),('S'),('T'),('U'),('V'),('W'),('X'),('Y'),('Z')) a(Chr)

CROSS JOIN 
(VALUES('0'),('1'),('2'),('3'),('4'),('5'),('6'),('7'),('8'),('9'),('A'),('B'),('C'),('D'),('E'),('F'),('G'),('H'),('I'),('J'),('K'),('L'),('M'),('N'),('O'),('P'),('Q'),('R'),('S'),('T'),('U'),('V'),('W'),('X'),('Y'),('Z')) b(Chr)

CROSS JOIN 
(VALUES('0'),('1'),('2'),('3'),('4'),('5'),('6'),('7'),('8'),('9'),('A'),('B'),('C'),('D'),('E'),('F'),('G'),('H'),('I'),('J'),('K'),('L'),('M'),('N'),('O'),('P'),('Q'),('R'),('S'),('T'),('U'),('V'),('W'),('X'),('Y'),('Z')) c(Chr)

WHERE concat(a.Chr,b.Chr,c.Chr)  > (
      SELECT TOP 1 
         CASE
              WHEN INSTRUCTION_CODE IS NULL 
              THEN ''  
              ELSE INSTRUCTION_CODE 
              END
      FROM ACCOUNT 
      ORDER BY INSTRUCTION_CODE DESC
                               )

ORDER BY REF;
```

I need to implement this request in a Java jUnit test. Here is what I did :

```
public static ResultSet getReference(java.sql.Connection con) throws SQLException {
        String query = "SELECT TOP 1 concat(a.Chr, b.Chr, c.Chr) AS REF "
                + "FROM "
                + "(VALUES('0'),('1'),('2'),('3'),('4'),('5'),('6'),('7'),('8'),('9'),('A'),('B'),('C'),('D'),('E'),('F'),('G'),('H'),('I'),('J'),('K'),('L'),('M'),('N'),('O'),('P'),('Q'),('R'),('S'),('T'),('U'),('V'),('W'),('X'),('Y'),('Z')) a(Chr) "
                + "CROSS JOIN "
                + "(VALUES('0'),('1'),('2'),('3'),('4'),('5'),('6'),('7'),('8'),('9'),('A'),('B'),('C'),('D'),('E'),('F'),('G'),('H'),('I'),('J'),('K'),('L'),('M'),('N'),('O'),('P'),('Q'),('R'),('S'),('T'),('U'),('V'),('W'),('X'),('Y'),('Z')) b(Chr) "
                + "CROSS JOIN "
                + "(VALUES('0'),('1'),('2'),('3'),('4'),('5'),('6'),('7'),('8'),('9'),('A'),('B'),('C'),('D'),('E'),('F'),('G'),('H'),('I'),('J'),('K'),('L'),('M'),('N'),('O'),('P'),('Q'),('R'),('S'),('T'),('U'),('V'),('W'),('X'),('Y'),('Z')) c(Chr) "
                + "WHERE concat(a.Chr, b.Chr, c.Chr)  > "
                + "(SELECT TOP 1 "
                + "     CASE WHEN INSTRUCTION_CODE IS NULL "
                + "     THEN '' "
                + "     ELSE INSTRUCTION_CODE "
                + "     END "
                + "FROM ACCOUNT order by INSTRUCTION_CODE DESC) "
                + "ORDER BY REF";
        java.sql.ResultSet rs = con.createStatement().executeQuery(query);

        return rs;
    }
```

Here's the error message I get when playing it :

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "SELECT TOP 1 CONCAT(A.CHR, B.CHR, C.CHR) AS REF FROM (VALUES('0'),('1'),('2'),('3'),('4'),('5'),('6'),('7'),('8'),('9'),('A'),('B'),('C'),('D'),('E'),('F'),('G'),('H'),('I'),('J'),('K'),('L'),('M'),('N'),('O'),('P'),('Q'),('R'),('S'),('T'),('U'),('V'),('W'),('X'),('Y'),('Z'))A([*]CHR) CROSS JOIN (VALUES('0'),('1'),('2'),('3'),('4'),('5'),('6'),('7'),('8'),('9'),('A'),('B'),('C'),('D'),('E'),('F'),('G'),('H'),('I'),('J'),('K'),('L'),('M'),('N'),('O'),('P'),('Q'),('R'),('S'),('T'),('U'),('V'),('W'),('X'),('Y'),('Z'))B(CHR) CROSS JOIN (VALUES('0'),('1'),('2'),('3'),('4'),('5'),('6'),('7'),('8'),('9'),('A'),('B'),('C'),('D'),('E'),('F'),('G'),('H'),('I'),('J'),('K'),('L'),('M'),('N'),('O'),('P'),('Q'),('R'),('S'),('T'),('U'),('V'),('W'),('X'),('Y'),('Z'))C(CHR) WHERE CONCAT(A.CHR, B.CHR, C.CHR)  > (SELECT TOP 1 CASE         WHEN INSTRUCTION_CODE IS NULL        THEN ''        ELSE INSTRUCTION_CODE        END FROM ACCOUNT ORDER BY ACBS_PAYMENT_INSTRUCTION_CODE DESC) ORDER BY REF ";
```

Is there anything you see I didn't ?

Thanx

Comment: it says there is an error in your sql statement. If you copy the select statement from the error message, does it run when you try manually (in your console)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you use a recent version of H2 when you work with H2 Console, and some old version (1.4.196 or older) in your application.

Such old versions don't support the derived column list syntax. You need to use a more recent version in your application too.